# Meaning of this line of code in C++

Tags: c++, rsa

I'm just started to pick up C and I am working on using the RSA cipher in my code. However, this line of code confuses me. Credits go to the author from this site [here](http://www.rajorshi.net/old/code_rsa.htm).

```
char* intmsg = new char[strlen(msg)*3 + 1];
```

This is the method which the line can be found.

```
inline void encrypt(char* msg,FILE* fout)
{
    /* This function actually does the encrypting of each message */

    unsigned int i;
    int tmp;
    char tmps[4];
    char* intmsg = new char[strlen(msg)*3 + 1];


    /* Here, (mpz_t) M is the messsage in gmp integer 
    *  and (mpz_t) c is the cipher in gmp integer */

    char ciphertext[1000];

    strcpy(intmsg,"");

    for(i=0;i<strlen(msg);i++)
    {
        tmp = (int)msg[i];

        /* print it in a 3 character wide format */
        sprintf(tmps,"%03d",tmp);

        strcat(intmsg,tmps);
    }

    mpz_set_str(M,intmsg,10);

    /* free memory claimed by intmsg */
    delete [] intmsg;

    /* c = M^e(mod n) */
    mpz_powm(c,M,e,n);

    /* get the string representation of the cipher */
    mpz_get_str(ciphertext,10,c);

    /* write the ciphertext to the output file */
    fprintf(fout,"%s\n",ciphertext);
}
```

Comment: The first bit you posted is C++, not C.

Comment: new is the keywod in c++ but you have tagged C only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That code line isn't actually C, it's C++.

```
    char* intmsg = new char[strlen(msg)*3 + 1];
```

Means to dynamically allocate a block of memory with room for the given number of chars, 3 times bigger + 1 than the original length of the `msg` string.

The C equivialent would be

```
    char* intmsg = malloc(strlen(msg)*3 + 1);
```

To deallocate that memory block, `delete []intmsg` is used in C++, while if you used `malloc` in C, you'd do `free(intmsg);`

Comment: Though actually, the entire code seems to be more like "C using `new`". :-)

Answer (score 2):

It creates an array of character which is 3 times larger than the list of characters stored in `msg` plus one character to store the string ending character '\0'.

More info on the C++ operator `new[]` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/)

Answer (score 1):

Its a line of C++, and its dynamically allocating an array of chars 3 times the length of string "msg" + 1 more (for the null terminator)

Answer (score 1):

This is C++ and the code allocates an array of char, the size of which is 3 times the length of the messages, plus one. The resulting pointer is assigned to `intmsg`.

Why does it do that? Because the message is converted, character by character, to a three digit per character decimal number in the loop with the `sprintf(tmps,"%03d",tmp);`.

Answer (score 0):

It's c++ code :

```
char* intmsg = new char[strlen(msg)*3 + 1];
```

This tells the compiler to create memory for `intmsg` on `heap` of length of memory block ie equal to "one more than the 3 times of length of the `msg`".

means After the execution of this line `intmsg` started pointing to the block of memory on `heap`.